# PowerShell script is unable to retrieve all the videos listed for a YouTube channel

Tags: powershell, youtube-api

I came up with the following PowerShell script, which when I enter the Channel_ID and my API Key, it generates a CSV file with approx. 500 of the 1500 videos on the channel.

```
# Define the YouTube API endpoint
$apiEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/"

# Prompt the user to enter a channel ID
$channelId = Read-Host "Enter the YouTube channel ID"

# Set the max results per page and initial page token
$maxResults = 500
$pageToken = ""

# Create an array to store the video information
$videoArray = @()

# Loop through the pages of video results until there are no more pages
do {
    # Define the API request URL for the current page
    $requestUrl = $apiEndpoint + "search?part=snippet&channelId=$channelId&type=video&maxResults=$maxResults&pageToken=$pageToken&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>"

    # Send the API request for the current page
    $apiResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $requestUrl

    # Loop through the videos on the current page and add them to the array
    foreach ($video in $apiResponse.items) {
        $date = [DateTime]::Parse($video.snippet.publishedAt).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        $videoInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Date = $date
            Title = $video.snippet.title
            URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$($video.id.videoId)"
        }
        $videoArray += $videoInfo
    }

    # Update the page token for the next page (if there is one)
    $pageToken = $apiResponse.nextPageToken

} until (-not $pageToken)

# Sort the video information by date in descending order (newest first)
$sortedVideos = $videoArray | Sort-Object -Property Date -Descending

# Save the video information to a CSV file on the desktop
$desktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$csvPath = "$desktopPath\YouTube Videos.csv"
$sortedVideos | Export-Csv $csvPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

# Get the total number of videos for the channel
$channelUrl = $apiEndpoint + "channels?part=statistics&id=$channelId&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>"
$channelInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $channelUrl
$totalVideos = $channelInfo.items.statistics.videoCount

# Check the number of videos in the CSV file
$csvVideos = $sortedVideos.Count

# Display the number of videos in the CSV file and the total number of videos for the channel
Write-Host "Saved $csvVideos videos to $csvPath"
Write-Host "YouTube channel $channelId has a total of $totalVideos videos"
```

I switched the MaxResults from 50 to 200, and 500, and I still get the same result.  The script is supposed to iterate through until all videos have been accounted for.

Comment: This API behavior is by design, you'll need to re-submit the request with an additional query parameter `publishedBefore=<timestampOfEarliestResultFromPreviousQuery>`

Comment: Search list has a max result of 50